# I am wanting to transfer pictures from a DSLR camera to my Raspberry Pi 3, but I am not sure how to do this?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, image

I was wanting to transfer pictures from my Sony SLT-A77 to my Raspberry Pi 3. I was thinking that this could be possible using Gphoto2, but I am not sure if there is an easier way, or if this way is even possible. I need it to check every 5 seconds or so to see if a new image has been captured and then send the picture to my Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 1):

[disclaimer] I havent actually had hands-on experience, but this is how I'd start

Most modern Cameras may support either [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) 
and in some cases PTP's extension [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).
The user manual that comes with your device should tell what is supported.

If you are looking to programatically access your DSLR camera's photos, 
there are some libraries such as [pyptpchdk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyptpchdk/0.2.1), 
[this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMTP) or [like this one](http://scottlobdell.me/2014/02/control-an-slr-camera-from-python-nikon-canon-sony-etc/).

Apparently someone has already worked on [this](http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-in-a-dslr-camera/) 
before, including periodically querying the camera for the list of images.